# Storage Service stores in localStorage but fails to retrieve it

Tags: angular, local-storage, angular17

I have an Angular service that successfully stores the key and value but fails to retrieve it.  Below is the code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class StorageService {
  constructor() {}

  // Store the value - (Note: This code works fine.  The key is userData and it stores an array of user credentials as value )

  async store(storageKey: string, value: any) {
    localStorage.setItem('key', storageKey);
    localStorage.setItem('value', value);
  }
  
  // Get the value - Here I provide the userData as key but I get a null value.  If put key in "key" then I get an error.  I have verified with console.log(key) that accurate key is passed to retrieve the value.

  async get(key: string) {
    const ret = localStorage.getItem(key);
    return JSON.parse(ret);
  } 
}
```

Comment: You are overwriting your localStorage by doing this. You will have two items in your localStorage key, value and when you are accessing it you are passing userData. That's why it's not working. Try to store items with storageKey as the first param and second param will be value. Also there is no need to make these methods async.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code solved for it. Basically, I had to add .then after the storageService.get function.

```
storageService.get('userData').then(res => { 
    if (res !== null) { 
      return true;
      } else {
        router.navigate(['login']);
        return false;
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

#### UPDATE

end user is having a asyncronous object returned so am switching to `async` / `await`. Not sure what storage service is in this context!

---

Please use `set` method of `localStorage` with the key and value in one call itself, you need to `JSON.stringify` the value to store it properly!

Then when getting the value, we can get the value correctly and it will get parsed easily!

Am not sure why we need async await, since all localStorage calls are synchronous. We can remove those also!

service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class StorageService {
  constructor() {}

  // Store the value - (Note: This code works fine.  The key is userData and it stores an array of user credentials as value )

  store(storageKey: string, value: any) {
    console.log(storageKey, value);
    localStorage.setItem(storageKey, JSON.stringify(value));
  }

  // Get the value - Here I provide the userData as key but I get a null value.  If put key in "key" then I get an error.  I have verified with console.log(key) that accurate key is passed to retrieve the value.

  async get(key: string) {
    console.log(key);
    const ret = await localStorage.getItem(key);
    return JSON.parse(<string>ret);
  }
}
```

main.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { StorageService } from './storage.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{ name }}!</h1>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.dev/overview">
      Learn more about Angular
    </a>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';

  constructor(private storageService: StorageService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.storageService.store('asdf', { test: 'qwerty' });
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(this.storageService.get('asdf'));
    }, 1000);
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-pnyqcx?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fstorage.service.ts,src%2Fmain.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)

Comment: It mostly works except that I get the following in my response: {"__zone_symbol__state":true,"__zone_symbol__value":{"user_id":4,"firstname":"John"}}. and I cannot access the values such as user_id or firstname.    Following is the code I used to get the userData - this.authUser = this.storageService.get('userData');
      console.log(JSON.stringify(this.authUser));  The code in the storage service was written as above.

Comment: This is what solved for me - this.storageService.get('userData').then(res => { this.authUser = res; });

Comment: I have given you 1 point.  However, sine there was no .then in your reply, it was not working for me.  If you can make the update, I can give mark your answer as the correct answer.

Comment: @techwestcoastsfosea updated my answer, out of curiosity what is storageService, is it the browser local storage? or something else?

Comment: It is localStorage

Comment: @techwestcoastsfosea check if you are storing a promise instead of a value, I think that is why the code change is even needed!

Comment: I am stroring an array where my key is  userData and value is {"user_id":4,"firstname":"John"}